# duplicate in sql server

Tags: sql-server

```
select a.AccountNumber,w.BillingAdmin
from dbo.ACCTHIST a left join dbo.WTABLE w on a.BillingClassKey = w.TablDKey
where a.AccountNumber in ('0000001779     W',
  '0000001779     W',
  '0000001779     W',
  '0000001779     W',
  '0000005502     W',
  '0000005502     W',
  '0000005502     W',
  '0000005502     W')
```

Result is:

```
  Account Number                    Billingadmin
  0000001779     W                  VB-Rajendrasingh R                                          
  0000005502     W                  NULL
  0000005502     W                  VB-Rajendrasingh R     
  0000005502     W                  VB-Rajendrasingh R
```

The question is I am puting  thrice  `account number  '0000001779     W'`, and thrice `'0000005502     W'`. Still I am getting One result for   `0000001779     W`    and three row for `0000005502     W`
                   Sorry I cant view the page in proper format ,so its difficult to put question in good format

Comment: What output do you expect? The code is behaving as expected based on the data

Answer (score 3):

Of course: you have 3 rows in WTABLE for `0000005502     W`

The IN clause ignore duplicates too so it is effectively

```
... in ('0000001779     W',  '0000005502     W')
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need one instance of each of your criteria in order to get all matching values anyway, try this.

```
select a.AccountNumber,w.BillingAdmin
from dbo.ACCTHIST a left join dbo.WTABLE w on a.BillingClassKey = w.TablDKey
where a.AccountNumber in ('0000001779     W',
  '0000005502     W')
```

you should get the same results.

Are you sure you have that value more than once in the data? To check try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(AccountNumber) From dbo.ACCTHIST WHERE AccountNumber = '0000001779     W'
```